# Compact embedding of fractional space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

> Is the space $H^\lambda((0,T); H^1(K))$ for $0 <\lambda <1$ where $K$ is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ compactly embedded in $L^2( (0,T) \times K)$?

$H^\lambda((0,T); H^1(K))\hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2((0,T) ; H^1(K))\hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2((0,T); L^2(K))$. 
Where can I find these type of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to prove $H^\gamma(0,T;H^1) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;L^2).$

1. $H^\gamma(0,T;H^1) \hookrightarrow H^\gamma(0,T;(H^1)') \cap L^2(0,T;H^1) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;L^2).$
2. $H^\gamma(0,T;H^1) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;H^1) \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;L^2).$

Note that you don't get that $L^2(0,T;H^1) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;L^2)$ as stated in the question. This is not true. For example take the sequence $f_n(t,x)=\sin(nt)x$.

**First:** Ben Schweizer "Partielle Differentialgleichungen", Theorem 24.2

> Let $V,X,V_0$ be Hilbert spaces such that $V \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow X \hookrightarrow V_0$. Then for $T<\infty$ and $\gamma>0$ we have
>   $$H^\gamma(0,T;V_0) \cap L^2(0,T;V) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;X).$$

**Second:** You get $H^\gamma(0,T) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T)$ from the fractional Sobolev embedding.

Comment: Is it also true that $H^\lambda((0,T);H^1(\mathbb{R}^d))$ is continuously embedded in $C((0,T); L^2(\mathbb{R}^d))$

Comment: @MathAnimal It's true at least for $\lambda >1/2$, see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654811/fractional-sobolev-embedding-into-l-infty).

Comment: Not for $\lambda <1/2$?